# Can't map hashmap in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i'm trying to use the content of a hashmap that is stored in *apiValidation* and looks like this:

```
{
  overall : {
    'corect':'40%',
    'incorect': '10%',
    'incert' : '50%',
  },
  forEachCategory: {
    'Organizational' : {
      'corect':'40%',
      'incorect': '10%',
      'incert' : '50%',
    },
    'Tehnic':{
      'corect':'40%',
      'incorect': '10%',
      'incert' : '50%',
    }
  }
  Organizational : {
    'Question 1' : [answer1,answer2,answer3]
    'Question 2' : [answer1,answer2,answer3]
  }
  scores : {
    'Tehnic' : {
      'question1' : 50,
      'question2' : 100,
      'question3' : 0,
    },
  }
}
```

i tried to access the data like this but it won't work:

```
Object.keys(apiValidation).forEach((overall,forEachCategory, Organizational, scores) => {
                                <>
                                {Object.keys(apiValidation[overall]).forEach((corect,incorect,incert) => {
                                    <>
                                    <h1>Overall</h1>
                                    <p>{apiValidation[overall][corect]}</p>
                                    <p>{apiValidation[overall][incorect]}</p>
                                    <p>{apiValidation[overall][incert]}</p>
                                    </>
                                })}
                                </>
                            })
                        }
```

Does anyone know what am i supposed to do? I want to display the content exactly how it is returned by the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing for each key:

```
{Object.keys(apiValidation).map((key) => (
  {key==='overall'? (#dosomething) : ()}
 
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the outer loop. The forEach and map loop synstax is the following.

```
Object.keys(object).forEach((key,index) => {
   ...
})
```

These loops don't unpack variables inside an array like you have tried using. Also try using map while you are rendering components as forEach does not return anything - meaning it won't render any of your desired components or JSX elements - whereas map will. So to give you an idea in your case:

```
Object.keys(apiValidation).map(key => {
    return nestedElements // Didn't write the logic for this but I hope you get what I mean
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(apiValidation).map((key) => {
  return (
    <>                                   
      {Object.keys(apiValidation[key]).map((type) => {
        return (
          <>
            <h1>{key}</h1>
            <p>{type.correct}</p>
            <p>{type.incorect}</p>
            <p>{type.incert}</p>
          </>
        )
      })}
     </>
   )
  })
}
```